# Evaluate $\iint(x^{2} + y^{2})dx\,dy$ over the area in the first quadrant bounded by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$.

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, jacobian, approximate-integration

Well I am stuck from the beginning. I have two methods:

**Method 1:**

$y=\sqrt{a^2−x^2}$
here $y$ varies from $\sqrt{a^2−x^2}$ to $0$
$x$ varies from $a$ to $0$
$\iint(x^2+y^2) dx\, dy= \int\left(x^2y+\frac{y^3}{3}\right) dx$
then I do not how to proceed

**Method 2:** Changing into polar coordinates.
$$\text{Let}\ x=r\cosθ, y=r\sinθ,$$
$$x^2+y^2= r^2$$
hence $r$ varies from $a$ to $0$;
$θ$ varies from $0$ to $90$

\begin{align*} 
J(x,\frac{y}{r},θ)&= r\\
 \iint(x^2+y^2) dx\, dy&=  \iint(x^2+y^2)J dr\, dθ\\
&=  \iint (r^2\cdot r)\ dr\, dθ\\
&= \iint r^3 dr\, dθ\\
&= \int \frac{r^4}{4} dθ\\
&= \int \frac{a^4}{4} dθ\\
&= \frac{a^4}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

But that is not the answer. The answer is actually said to be $\frac{a^5}{5}$. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If $a,x,y$ were measured in meters, you would be integrating something in square meters over an area, also measured in square meters. Therefore the answer will be measured in meters to the fourth power. Therefore you should be suspicious over a suggestion that $a^5$ would appear.

Answer (score 3):

About first method. You need to add the limits of integration

$$\iint_{x^2+y^2<a^2 \\x>0,y>0}(x^2+y^2) dx\, dy=\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} (x^2+y^2)dy\,dx=\\
\int_0^a \left.\left(x^2y+\frac{y^3}{3}\right)\right|_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\int_0^a \left(x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{1}{3}(a^2-x^2)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)dx=\\ \int_0^a \left(\frac{2}{3}x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{1}{3}a^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)dx$$

Standard substitution for such integrals is $x=a\sin t$ and this leads to the same result as in your second method but needs more calculation:

$$\int_0^a \left(\frac{2}{3}x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{1}{3}a^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)dx=\\
\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{2}{3}a^3\sin^2 t \cos t+\frac{1}{3}a^3\cos t\right)a\cos t dt=\\
a^4\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\sin^2 t \cos^2 t+\frac{1}
{3}\cos^2 t\right) dt=\\
a^4\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\sin^2 2t+\frac{1}{6}\cos 2t+\frac{1}{6}\right) dt=\\
a^4\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{12}\cos 4t+\frac{1}{6}\cos 2t+\frac{1}{6}\right) dt=\\
a^4\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{12}\cos 4t+\frac{1}{6}\cos 2t\right) dt=\\
a^4\left.\left(\frac{t}{4}-\frac{1}{48}\sin 4t+\frac{1}{12}\sin 2t\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=\pi/2}=\frac{\pi a^4}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you make the change of variable $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$, the proposed integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\iint_{R}(x^{2} + y^{2})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{a}r^{3}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\pi a^{4}}{8}
\end{align*}

So your calculations are correct!

Comment: OP has described this under "method 2" :-)

Comment: But OP was sure, that this result is wrong, and answer is that result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> **Method 1:**

> $y=\sqrt{a^2−x^2}$
> here $y$ varies from $\sqrt{a^2−x^2}$ to $0$
> $x$ varies from $a$ to $0$
> $\iint(x^2+y^2) dx\, dy= \int\left(x^2y+\frac{y^3}{3}\right) dx$
> then I do not how to proceed

You do the innermost integral first, and you put the limits of integration into it to remove one of the variables. Let $b\equiv \sqrt{a^2-y^2}$ then

$$
\int_{0}^a\int_{0}^b\left(x^2+y^2\right) dx \;dy
=
\int_{0}^a\left[{x^3\over 3}+x y^2\right]_{0}^b dy\\
=\int_{0}^a b\left({b^2\over 3}+y^2\right) dy
$$

Substitute $y=a\sin t$, then $dy=a\cos t\;dt$ and $b=a\cos t$
and you get
$$
{1\over 3}a^4\int \cos^2 t(\cos^2 t+3\sin^2t) dt
$$
Now
$$
\int \cos^2 t(\cos^2 t+3\sin^2t) dt=\int \cos^2t+2(\cos t\sin t)^2 dt\\
=\frac12t-\frac14\sin2t +\frac14t-\frac1{16}\sin 4t +C
$$
Here I have used the double-angle formulas repeatedly.

Substitute in the limits and you get the same answer.